# How do I narrow down the condition of an explicit wait to a given SearchContext?

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-java

I would like to wait until a specific view disappears. In general, I can do it with the following code:

```kotlin
val wait = WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3)) // where driver is e.g. WebDriver
val condition = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.id("my.app:id/someId") // or another locator, e.g. XPath
)
wait.until(condition)
```

However, that way is not very precise.

Imagine a scenario with two different views matching the same predicate (locator). In the example below I used the "by ID" locator but it could be anything else, too.

In the image below, there are 3 views:

- view "A" that matches my predicate ("by ID")
- view "B" that contains view "C"
- view "C" that matches my predicate ("by ID")

[image: Two views matching the same locator]

When I want to just find view "C", e.g. in order to click it, I can do this:

```kotlin
driver.findElement(By.id("anotherId")).findElement("someId").click()
```

so I can narrow down the search for view "C" by searching for view "B" first, when I know it contains view "C".

That is possible because `WebElement` returned by `findElement` method implements `SearchContext` interface, just like `WebDriver` does. Therefore, I can choose whether I want to search on the whole screen or inside a specific `WebElement`.

How can I narrow down the search in case of waiting for the view to disappear?

Ideally, I would expect something like:

```kotlin
ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(
    searchContext, // either a driver or WebElement
    By.id(...) // the locator
)
```

but I haven't found anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked throw the `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions` methods..

There are some similar methods:

- `visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(final By parent, final By childLocator)`
- `visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(final WebElement element, final By childLocator)`

But no the same methods for `invisibility`.

So, I suggest implementing the custom one:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions

public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> invisibilityOfNestedElementLocated(WebElement parent, By nested) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        private boolean wasFound = false;

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            wasFound = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(parent.findElements(nested)).apply(driver);
            return wasFound;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("element \"%s\" from parent \"%s\", found: \"%b\"", nested.toString(), parent.toString(), wasFound);
        }
    };
}
```

And for your example:

```
WebElement searchContext = driver.findElement(By.id("anotherId");
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(
    invisibilityOfNestedElementLocated(searchContext, By.id('someId'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess this is close enough to what I wanted so I'm marking it as accepted. However, I'm open to better alternatives (if there are any).

Comment: @AndrzejZabost I think you can change the first argument type from `WebElement` to `SearchContext` and this will work with driver arg too.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I know  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> stalenessOf​(WebElement element)

Wait until an element is no longer attached to the DOM.